# phantomjs + webpack not working

Tags: javascript, node.js, phantomjs, webpack

npm i -g phantom

> /
>
> > weak@0.4.1 install C:\Users\muzo0\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\phantom\node_modules\dnode\node_modules\weak
> >     node-gyp rebuild
>
> C:\Users\muzo0\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\phantom\node_modules\dnode\node_modules\weak>if
>   not defined npm_config_n ode_gyp (node
>   "C:\DevLibs\nodejs\node_modules\npm\bin\node-gyp-bin\....\node_modules\node-gyp\bin\node-gyp.js"
>   rebuild  )  else (rebuild) Building the projects in this solution one
>   at a time. To enable parallel build, please add the "/m" switch.
>   weakref.cc
>        Creating library C:\Users\muzo0\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\phantom\node_modules\dnode\node_modules\weak\buil
>   d\Release\weakref.lib and object
>   C:\Users\muzo0\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\phantom\node_modules\dnode\node_modu
>   les\weak\build\Release\weakref.exp   Generating code   Finished
>   generating code   weakref.vcxproj ->
>   C:\Users\muzo0\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\phantom\node_modules\dnode\node_modules\weak\build
>   \Release\weakref.node phantom@0.7.2
>   C:\Users\muzo0\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\phantom ├──
>   win-spawn@2.0.0 ├── traverse@0.6.6 ├── shoe@0.0.15 (sockjs@0.3.7) └──
>   dnode@1.2.1 (jsonify@0.0.0, dnode-protocol@0.2.2, weak@0.4.1)

webpack.config.js

```
module.exports = {
    entry: './src/main.js',
    output: {
        filename: 'dist.js'
    },
    module: {
        loaders: [
            { test: /\.js$/, loader: 'babel', exclude: /node_modules/ },
            { test: /\.json$/, loader: 'json'}
        ]
    },
    target: "node"
};
```

webpack --hot

> Hash: d94ab9a8045078efe92c Version: webpack 1.10.0 Time: 2807ms
>   Asset     Size  Chunks             Chunk Names dist.js  1.28 MB
>   0  [emitted]  main
>       + 180 hidden modules
>
> WARNING in ./~/phantom/~/dnode/~/weak/~/bindings/bindings.js Critical
>   dependencies: 76:22-40 the request of a dependency is an expression
>   76:43-53 the request of a dependency is an expression  @
>   ./~/phantom/~/dnode/~/weak/~/bindings/bindings.js 76:22-40 76:43-53
>
> WARNING in ./~/phantom/~/shoe/~/sockjs/lib/utils.js Module not found:
>   Error: Cannot resolve module 'rbytes' in
>   c:\Users\muzo0\Desktop\new_tele_bot\node_modules\phantom\node
>   _modules\shoe\node_modules\sockjs\lib  @ ./~/phantom/~/shoe/~/sockjs/lib/utils.js 7:13-30
>
> WARNING in ./~/phantom/~/dnode/~/weak/~/bindings/README.md Module
>   parse failed:
>   c:\Users\muzo0\Desktop\new_tele_bot\node_modules\phantom\node_modules\dnode\node_modules\weak\node_
>   modules\bindings\README.md Line 2: Unexpected token === You may need
>   an appropriate loader to handle this file type. | node-bindings |
>   ============= | ### Helper module for loading your native module's .node file |  @ ./~/phantom/~/dnode/~/weak/~/bindings ^./.*$

node dest.js

> module.js:338
>       throw err;
>             ^ Error: Cannot find module 'c:\Users\muzo0\Desktop\new_tele_bot\dest.js'
>       at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:336:15)
>       at Function.Module._load (module.js:278:25)
>       at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:501:10)
>       at startup (node.js:129:16)
>       at node.js:814:3

c:\Users\muzo0\Desktop\new_tele_bot>phantomjs

> 'phantomjs' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
>   operable program or batch file.

main.js

```
import phantom from 'phantom';
```

OS: win 10
npm: 2.7.4